# Appcelerator - Detect keyboard hide android

Tags: javascript, android, keyboard, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have a `webview` into my Android app. My html has a `textarea` and I want to know when the user hides the keyboard with the android back button.

On Titanium the `android:back` event doesn't work, it isn't fired when the keyboard is hided.

And the `blur()` event doesn't work too because when the keyboard is hided the `textarea` doesn't lose the focus.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `androidback` on any [`Ti.UI.Window`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window) or [`Ti.UI.TabGroup`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup) top-level container. It was called `android:back` until 3.0.0. And for the `blur()` event, you can use the [`Ti.UI.Android.hideSoftKeyboard()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Android-method-hideSoftKeyboard) method.